# Right Clicking on a particular Web Page in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to *Right click on Google Maps page*, So far I am able to create the object `ie`, navigate to the page and search for a particular address.

But in the next step I have to click on the bottom of Address marker ***(Blue Dot)***

[image]

After the click, I want to select `What's Here` from the options.

After the selection, I use the line

`ie.document.getElementsByClassName("link-like widget-reveal-card-lat-lng")(0).innerText` to get the co-ordinates of the Place.

**Code so Far:**

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "https://www.google.com/maps"

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
ie.document.getElementById("searchboxinput").Value = "Signature Tower GurGaon"


ie.document.getElementById("searchbox-searchbutton").Click

MsgBox "After Manually clicking What's Here, press ok"
```

Basically I want to automate that Manual part. What are the elements that needs to be clicked for the right click and how do I identify the point where to click.

---

**Alternate:**

Just found that, those lat-long are also part of the a href by

```
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("gb_9d gb_2 gb_ob")(0).href
```

So there is no need to right click.

But I am still interested to know how to Right Click it.

Comment: What ever you actually try to achive by that, I recomend to use the API Google provides instead of scraping around. This is much more reliable and will survive the changes to the code that Google does in several intervals.

Comment: I am using the API using Python @Pᴇʜ, but API have it's limitations, as it only takes the complete addresses, Here with this I can look for locations by Location Name, like in the example.

Comment: Are the correct lat lon 28.4665403,77.0556526?  or 28.4636862 77.054257  ?

Comment: Correct ones are `28.4665356,77.0578413` The last ones in the [Link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Unitech+Signature+Tower/@28.4666336,77.0567461,17z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x0:0x0!2zMjjCsDI3JzQ5LjMiTiA3N8KwMDMnMTUuMyJF!3b1!8m2!3d28.4636862!4d77.054257!3m4!1s0x0:0xc8d48f7c12c1fd65!8m2!3d28.4665356!4d77.0578413)

Comment: @Mikku, you can search by location names with [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro). You should prefer the API because code on Google Maps can change without notifcation and break your code. To query the API have a look at [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) to send requests and receive responses.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher , You are Right, but My Problem is that if a user has 1000 address to GeoCode and Places API & Geocoding API returns only 900 accurate addresses, the User have to Manually search the Rest 100, which takes a lot of time, sometimes Hours. So What I wanted to build was a type of Assistant. So using this code, user can select the cell with address Information > Click on a Shortcut > that will open up maps in Browser with the Search of the string from cell > User can modify the search, change the selection etc > and after fining the desired result > Click on Proceed Msgbox

Comment: That was Holdinng up the Code. Which will fetch the Co-Ordinates of the Location. So it's saving like 60 Secs from a 1.5 Minute Manual Task.

Comment: OK, I missed that part ;( , but Places API should be able to return location names to Coordinates.  if you create an Internet Explorer using`With Events`, then you can catcht the left-click event and get coordinates, then send them to places in VBA..

Comment: [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=de#place_search_requests) should be the source of ' What is here'.  Why are your addresses so badly geocoded? Maybe you can improve that.

Comment: I appreciate your Efforts @ComputerVersteher, but the thing is sometimes we have cases where we just have a name of a place and Country, now there can be many places witht the same name, so API is no good in that case, we have to rely on the Manual Intervention and verify that the Result is Correct, which is done by going to Maps and checking out if the location is correct or not. This code will help relieve the excess time a User takes to open Maps and save co-ordinates from it. Manual intervention is still there.

Comment: I understand your needs, But i would use the api as it is more reliable and does the same. Of course, if you discover how to open the contect menu that would be  less code, but you can archive the same (even better) with the effort using the api (after click on map. IE send Places request, whose respone you can display to the user. You shouls add your last 2 huge comments to question and then delete them as dicussion grows (and auto-chat seems offline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can put the search term directly into the first navigate.

```
IE.navigate "https://www.google.com/maps" & "/search/Signature Tower GurGaon"
```

Your wait loop should check `.Busy` and `.ReadyState`

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
```

And as you already found out the coordinates are in the source code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.google.com/maps" & "/search/Signature Tower GurGaon"

    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

    Dim GetLocation As String
    GetLocation = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("gb_9d gb_2 gb_ob")(0).href
    GetLocation = Right$(GetLocation, Len(GetLocation) - InStr(1, GetLocation, "%40") - 2)
    GetLocation = Left$(GetLocation, InStr(1, GetLocation, "&") - 1)

    Dim Location() As String
    Location = Split(GetLocation, "%2C")

    Debug.Print "Lat", Location(0)
    Debug.Print "Lon", Location(1)
    Debug.Print "zoom", Location(2)

End Sub
```

Will result in

```
Lat           28.4636862
Lon           77.054257
zoom          16z
```

Comment: Just wanted to give you an information, the Lat/Long you are pulling out in the above code are the co-ordinates for the center of the screen. The Correct co-ordinates are present in the end  of `href`, I have manipulated the string to get the correct info. Just wanted to update you :) @pᴇʜ

Comment: @Mikku Can you show us the correct co-ordinates? and how did you get it?

Comment: I saw your suggestion in the first post. Thanks a lot